# If /ELse In SQL Using Parameter to distinguish a Percentage to be added to Value Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, percentage

I am trying to write a SQL stored procedure using If/Else that takes the Integer from IncPercent as a parameter and IF the IncPercent is under 10 treats that as a percentage to be added to the value column on OrderDetails table. ELSE if it is 10 or above it only adds 10 percent to the value column on OrderDetails table.

```
    Create Procedure spAddPercentage
    (
    @IncPercent int
    )
    AS
    BEGIN 
    IF @IncPercent < 10  SELECT Value From OrderDetails
    UPDATE OrderDetails
    THEN Value * @IncPercent / 100 + Value
    END IF
    ELSE @IncPercent > 10 SELECT Value FROM OrderDetails
    UPDATE OrderDetails 
    THEN  Value * 1.1
    END
```

UPDATE: This is the code I used that worked

```
      Create Procedure spAddPercentage
      (
      @IncPercent int
      )
      AS
      BEGIN 
      IF @IncPercent < 10
       BEGIN
        UPDATE OrderDetails
        SET Value = Value * ( 1 + @IncPercent / 100.0)
        END
       ELSE 
      UPDATE OrderDetails
      SET Value = Value * 1.1
      END
```

Comment: Procedural code like stored procedures is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sql-server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you writing stored procedures if you don't even know the basic syntax for an `update`?  I would expect something like this:

```
UPDATE OrderDetails
    SET Value = (CASE WHEN @IncPercent <= 10
                      THEN Value * ( 1 + @IncPercent / 100.0)
                      ELSE Value * 1.1
                 END);
```

Your syntax looks closest to SQL Server, so I'm assuming that is the database.  The code would look quite similar in other databases.

Here are some of the problems with your code:

- `UPDATE` takes a table name, not a column name.
- SQL Server does integer division, so 1/100 = 0, not 0.01.
- `SUM()` is used for aggregation not for adding numbers in the same row.
- SQL Server does not have `END IF`.  No language that I'm familiar with has `END ELSE`.
- Do not start stored procedure definitions with "sp".  It is too close to "sp_", which means something special in SQL Server ([here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) is a good explanation).

Comment: Thank you but what about IF ELSE statement as that is what I am trying to learn. Have never used CASE yet in my learning as I am only a student.

Comment: @Richoz . . . Learn `CASE` .  It is ANSI standard SQL and the better way to answer this question.  You should use `IF` when it is the appropriate method to use, and that is not the case for this update.

Comment: Thanks I used your answer and modified it into a if else statement and it worked